# does session persists between server hops

Tags: session-management

Lets say we have server A where a user has maintained a session and on some particular actions he is taken to a different server say B. So if he comes back to A within the session expiration time will his session with A persists or not?

Comment: Are you referring to HTTP sessions?

Comment: for cookie based HTTP(s) sessions it is correct - cookies are not cleared until their expiration time comes - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie. Underlaying TCP connection will be re-established. Anyway, i think you need to improve this question. Whad do you mean by session here?